# Can't build gem5 (ARM) due to missing -lgrpc++

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, gem5

I am trying to build gem5 (ARM) using

> scons build/ARM/gem5.opt -j 1

But I keep getting this error

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgrpc++
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> scons: *** [build/ARM/gem5.opt] Error 1
> scons: building terminated because of errors.

I can't seem to find any information on this missing file. It's not anywhere in the computer afaik and google isn't helping much either

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to instal the `grpc` package. It contains the missing file, `libgrpc++.so`,  most likely in `/usr/lib/libgrpc++.so`. See also Ubuntu packages site: https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/impish/misc/grpc